# Ms Excel "Next without for"

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I no this question has come up numerous times, I have read through them all and have come across this problem in my code before and have been able to solove it.

```
If count > 1 Then
           For Each Match1 In Regex.Execute(text)
           myOtherSheet.Cells(j, 1).Value = WkSht.Cells(r, 2)
           If Macth1 = "" Then
           Exit For
           Else
           myOtherSheet.Cells(j, 2).Value = Match1
           j = j + 1
           Next Match1
           End If
```

The code gives the error on the Next Match1 line, This usually happens to me when I am forgetting to close a loop but everything seems to be ok here, Is the exit for in the INNNER if casue the program to not run ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Miss `End If` before `Next`. Pay attention!!!

Properly formatting your code should avoid this mistakes.

Comment: The count > 1 Then has an End If further down in my code, The problem was My End If should have been before the Match1 not after ! thanks for the guy guys :)

Answer (score 0):

`End If` missing before Next Match1

You can use the Smart Indenter add on which will make the code more readable and fix the syntax issues like this one.
[Download Smart Indenter](http://www.oaltd.co.uk/indenter/indentpage.asp)

```
If count > 1 Then
    For Each Match1 In Regex.Execute(text)
        myOtherSheet.Cells(j, 1).Value = WkSht.Cells(r, 2)
        If Macth1 = "" Then
            Exit For
        Else
            myOtherSheet.Cells(j, 2).Value = Match1
            j = j + 1
        End If
        Next Match1
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I add to @LS_dev answer that if you allways use indentation then you are more likely to get all the `End If` and `Next` right.

As your code would look like this with indentation:

```
If Count > 1 Then
    For Each Match1 In Regex.Execute(Text)
        myOtherSheet.Cells(j, 1).Value = WkSht.Cells(r, 2)
        If Macth1 = "" Then
            Exit For
        Else
            myOtherSheet.Cells(j, 2).Value = Match1
            j = j + 1
        ' Missing End If
    Next Match1
End If
```